# How to store screen output of Scrapy into a file in Linux

Tags: linux, scrapy

I often use

```
self.logger.info('Parse function called on %s', response.url)
```

to debug Scrapy project. However, when there are lot of items crawled, those log information will be embedded inside a lot of non-useful information.

What I want is to store the screen output into a file, so that I can do search, do text editing, etc.

I tried:

```
scrapy crawl xxx_spider >> my_log
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your script may be writing to something other than stdout, such as stderr. Try:

```
     $ scrapy crawl xxx_spider  &> test_log
```

If it is indeed writing script output to stderr, you may want to direct stderr to stdout in the future and might want to consider changing the location to which logger outputs text.